# Downloading Lejos Firmware w/ eclipse plug-in (Linux Mint 17.3)

Tags: linux, eclipse, linux-mint, firmware, lejos-nxj

So I've just switched to d to Linux Mint rosa from Windows 10. I'm trying to figure out how download the firmware through eclipse. Whenever I click the plug-in and then the firmware I get;

"starting nxjflashg failed
org.lejos.nxt.ldt.util.LeJOSNXJException: NXJ_HOME is not set. Please specify it in the plug-in's preferences
See Eclipse error log for detailed stack trace."

I know when I was using windows 10 I had to change environmental variables and download the NXJ drivers also, I'm not sure how to do this w/ Linux

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 steps to flash a NXT on Linux with eclipse (once Java is working):

- install the libusb driver
- install LeJOS
- install the LeJOS eclipse pugin

I think you only installed the eclipse plugin, so you need to follow the instructions here : http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/tutorial/Preliminaries/GettingStartedLinux.htm

Summary :

- `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev ant` (install libusb driver and ant, a kind of `make` for java)
- download leJOS, unizp it and put it where you want (`/opt` for instance)
- set the `NXT_HOME` in the window > Preferences > leJOS NXT > NXJ_HOME to the path you copied leJOS
- run `ant` in `$NXJ_HOME/build` to build the usb driver
- to access to your USB port without `su` rights

  - edit your udev rules (1)
  - add your user to the group lego (`sudo groupadd lego && sudo gpasswd -a $USER lego`)
  - log out and log in to update the rules

(1) udev rule : `vim /etc/udev/rules.d/70-lego.rules`

```
# Lego NXT brick in normal mode
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVER=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0694", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002", GROUP="lego", MODE="0660"
# Lego NXT brick in firmware update mode (Atmel SAM-BA mode)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVER=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6124", GROUP="lego", MODE="0660"
```